# meaning of ‘calculated' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> He comes in last: I am not looking at the arch, yet I see him enter. I
>   try to concentrate my attention on those netting-needles, on the
>   meshes of the purse I am forming—I wish to think only of the work I
>   have in my hands, to see only the silver beads and silk threads that
>   lie in my lap; whereas, I distinctly behold his figure, and I
>   inevitably recall the moment when I last saw it; just after I had
>   rendered him, what he deemed, an essential service, and he, holding my
>   hand, and looking down on my face, surveyed me with eyes that revealed
>   a heart full and eager to overflow; in whose emotions I had a part.
>   How near had I approached him at that moment! What had occurred since,
>   **calculated** to change his and my relative positions? 
>  (Jane Eyre)

What’s the meaning of ‘calculated’ in the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than in any way indicating calculation or planning,  *calculated* here serves as a synonym of *apt* or *likely*.  OED 1 shows the following two senses of *calculated*:

> 1. Reckoned, estimated, devised with forethought
> 2. Fitted, suited, fit, apt; of a nature or character proper or likely to. [eg]  1722 De Foe ... The state of life that I was now in was ... perfectly  calculated to make a man completely happy.

It is the second sense that applies in the quoted passage.

Answer (score 4):

It means "planned or intended for a specific purpose".

The most common meaning of "calculate" is to find the result of a mathematical problem. Like, "We entered all the numbers into the computer and it calculated the results." When someone says that an action that a person took was "calculated to do X", he means that it was very carefully and deliberately planned, like the person had turned the whole situation into a math problem and then calculated how to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

I think that last sentence could be rewritten like this:

> What are the things *calculated to change his and my relative positions* that happened since that moment?

I hope this is what you were asking and that it makes sense :)